# How to repair corrupted packets for a corrupted copied file?

Tags: c#, copy, md5, crc32

The problem is how to repair not how to copy.

So, if we copied a file and we created a HashMap for this file (using MD5 or CRC32 in C#) before and after copying, so that we can check after copying that the file has been fully copied without any corruption.

Let's assume that we find a corruption packet in this copied file.
The question is: besides re-copying the file, is there anything we can do to only fix the corrupted packet using MD5 or CRC32 or any other technique in C#?

Comment: No, crc is not an error correcting number, it only tells you that there is a problem, not where it is. Pretty much the same with md5. You don't have to resend the whole file, just the packet. TCP does a lot of this for you.

Comment: is there anyway to repair it beside TCP?

Comment: The easiest way is to ask for the packet again, ECC's may be able to fix small errors, but just don't contain enough information to reconstruct entire packets (unless very small).

Comment: You say that you are able to "find" a corrupted packet. You therefore have some error detection code (not ECC!), such as parity, in place already. You can therefore identify and retransmit the missing packet. If you don't like TCP, you don't need to use it, you can do the retransmission over simpler protocols as well. Without retransmission you can reconstruct the missing data only in principle: Assuming that your hash is cryptographically secure, you can retry with all possible bit combinations of missing data data in the packet until the hash for the file matches.This will take forever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What you want is a Reed-Solomon code, which is an error-correction code. Depending on how much check information you add, it can correct for a limited number of errors in the message. This is only useful if your error channel is likely to only introduce a small number of errors.

Reed-Solomon codes are good at correcting long bursts of errors, which is part of how they made CDs possible. Reed-Solomon codes can correct the burst of errors causes by a macroscopic scratch on the CD, where the encoded bits are microscopic.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Adler said, it is better to use Reed-Solomon to repair the corrupted Pakets.
also, the system method `File.Copy()` is already checking if there is any corruption in the copied Pakets.